# Whenever I Insert Data in Database It Saves an Extra Row in Database

Tags: c#, sql

[layout and db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjnIZ.jpg)

```
if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(b.ToString())))
{
    string connection = "server=127.0.0.1; database=accounts;user=root; password='';";
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connection);
    conn.Open();
    string SQL = "INSERT INTO payment_voucher (voucher_no, paid_to, date, account_cr, account_dr, description, student_emp_id, amount, total ) values ('" + label8.Text.ToString() + "','" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + dateTimePicker1.Value + "','" + a + "','" + b + "', '" + richTextBox1.Text + "', '" + textBox3.Text + "', '" + textBox4.Text + "', '" + label11.Text.ToString() + "');";
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(SQL, conn);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

}
```

i dont know why it is happening. front end is in C#.

Comment: are you sure it's inserting two and not just READING two?  Check your database and read queries.

Comment: What @DanRayson said, or could there be a trigger on the table that inserts an extra row?

Comment: First of all use parametrized query to avoid SQL Injection attack. Then check if your table has INSERT trigger.

Comment: checkout the layout and DB picture.

Comment: i am working on a C# desktop app not on web app.

Answer (score 1):

That statement will not insert two rows.

You have a few things to check here:

- Check if that code is being called twice
- Check if there is other similar code that is also being called
- Make sure there are no triggers on the table that do an additional insert
- Make sure you don't have some weird Try/Catch/Fail logic that causes that entire thing to be run again

And most importantly:

- Run a SQL Profiler trace to see exactly what is being sent to the database

Query the table when you've checked those with a raw `SELECT` query in Enterprise Manager and make sure there is one row.

That code above would not duplicate rows unless called twice.